# DisplayAttribute - How can I set a default Resource?

Tags: c#, attributes, data-annotations

I have a poco class Product

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id {get;set;}

    [RequiredEx]
    public string ProductName {get;set;}
}
```

the RequiredEx attribute ist just a little wrapper around RequiredAttribute (System.ComponentMode.DataAnnotations` so I don't have to specify the Resource type / name every time.

```
public class RequiredExAttribute : System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute
{
    public RequiredExAttribute()
    {
        this.ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ModelResources);
        this.ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorMessage.Required";
    }
}
```

Now I want to decorate my property with the Display attribute

```
[Display(ResourceType=typeof(ModelResources), Name="Product.ProductName")]
public string ProductName { get; set; }
```

In this case I can't just inherit from DisplayAttribute because it is sealed. Is there any chance for me not to have to type `ResourceType=typeof(ModelResources)` everytime I use this Attribute?

Comment: should the last line read "In this case I can't just inherit from `DisplayAttribute` " ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the attribute is `sealed`, and isn't part of a more complex OO model (the base class is just `Attribute`, and there are no interfaces implemented), I can't see that you have any options available to you here. Basically, I expect the answer is simply: "you will heed to specify the `ResourceType` every time".

Answer (score 0):

If you're only using the `Name` property of the `DisplayAttribute` you can achieve this by inheriting from the (older) `DisplayNameAttribute`, which is not sealed:

```
using System.Resources;

namespace System.ComponentModel
{
    public class LocalisedDisplayNameAttribute
        : DisplayNameAttribute
    {
        readonly ResourceManager m_resourceManager;
        readonly string          m_resourceName;

        public LocalisedDisplayNameAttribute(ResourceManager resourceManager,
                                             string          resourceName)
            : base()
        {
            m_resourceManager = resourceManager;
            m_resourceName    = resourceName;
        }

        public override string DisplayName
        {
            get { return m_resourceManager.GetString(m_resourceName); }
        }
    }
}
```

You can then set up display attributes for your common string resources:

```
public class DisplayBizAttribute
    : LocalisedDisplayNameAttribute
{
    public DisplayBizAttribute(string resourceName)
        : base(StringsBiz.ResourceManager, resourceName)
    {
    }
}

public class DisplayWebAttribute
    : LocalisedDisplayNameAttribute
{
    public DisplayBizAttribute(string resourceName)
        : base(StringsWeb.ResourceManager, resourceName)
    {
    }
}
```

And then you can localise your property display names very easily, with string literals or constants:

```
[DisplayBiz("ProductName")]
public string ProductName { get; set; }

[DisplayBiz(StringNames.PHONE_NUMBER)]
public string ProductName { get; set; }

[DisplayWeb("EmailAddress")]
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
```

**Update**

This can be improved by declaring an enum in each attribute class, and changing the constructor, or adding a new one:

```
public class DisplayBizAttribute
    : LocalisedDisplayNameAttribute
{
    public enum Name
    {
        PhoneNumber,
        ProductName,
    }

    public DisplayBizAttribute(Name resourceName)
        : base(StringsBiz.ResourceManager, resourceName.ToString())
    {
    }
}
```

Now you don't have to use hard-coded strings.

```
[DisplayBiz(DisplayBiz.Name.ProductName)]
public string ProductName { get; set; }
```

This is something you do a lot, so I like to add a `using` to shorten the enum:

```
using Biz = System.ComponentModel.DisplayBiz.Name;
...
[DisplayBiz(Biz.PhoneNumber)]
public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
```